# Wordnet Find Synonyms

Tags: nlp, wordnet, synonym, jaws-wordnet

I am searching for a way to find all the synonyms of a particular word using wordnet. I am using JAWS.

**For example:**

**love(v):** admire, adulate, be attached to, be captivated by, be crazy about, be enamored of, be enchanted by, be fascinated with, be fond of, be in love with, canonize, care for, cherish, choose, deify, delight in, dote on, esteem, exalt, fall for, fancy, glorify, go for, gone on....

**love(n):** 
Synonym : adulation, affection, allegiance, amity, amorousness, amour, appreciation, ardency, ardor, attachment, case*, cherishing, crush, delight, devotedness, devotion, emotion, enchantment, enjoyment, fervor, fidelity, flame, fondness, friendship, hankering, idolatry, inclination, infatuation, involvement

In a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745631/trying-to-find-synonyms-using-wordnet-java-api) user Ram has pointed to some code but that does not suffice as it just gives a vastly different output:

love, passion: any object of warm affection or devotion beloved, dear, dearest, honey, 
love: a beloved person; used as terms of endearment
love, sexual love, erotic love: a deep feeling of sexual desire and attraction
love: a score of zero in tennis or squash
sexual love, lovemaking, making love, love, love life: sexual activities (often including sexual intercourse) between two people
love: have a great affection or liking for

So how do I achieve it and is wordnet suited for what I want to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sticking with just WordNet, you *could* try to use semantic similarity to determine if two words (synsets) are similar enough to be synonyms. Below is a quick example that came from modifying another of my answers on [semantic similarity using WordNet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638272/1988505).

It does have its problems though:

- Antonyms are mixed in with synonyms
- It is **slow**! (as it has to check all ~117k synsets)

Still, it produces more synonyms than using `lemma_names` alone, so I leave it here in case it might be useful (in conjunction with something else perhaps).

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> def syn(word, lch_threshold=2.26):
    for net1 in wn.synsets(word):
        for net2 in wn.all_synsets():
            try:
                lch = net1.lch_similarity(net2)
            except:
                continue
            # The value to compare the LCH to was found empirically.
            # (The value is very application dependent. Experiment!)
            if lch >= lch_threshold:
                yield (net1, net2, lch)


>>> for x in syn('love'):
    print x
```

Code above outputs:

```
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('feeling.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('conditioned_emotional_response.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('emotion.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('worship.n.02'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('anger.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('fear.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('fear.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('anxiety.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('joy.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('love.n.01'), 3.6375861597263857)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('agape.n.02'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('agape.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('filial_love.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('ardor.n.02'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('amorousness.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('puppy_love.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('devotion.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('benevolence.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('beneficence.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('heartstrings.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('lovingness.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('warmheartedness.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('loyalty.n.02'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('hate.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.01'), Synset('emotional_state.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('content.n.05'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('object.n.04'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('antipathy.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('bugbear.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('execration.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('center.n.06'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('hallucination.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('infatuation.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.02'), Synset('love.n.02'), 3.6375861597263857)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('person.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('lover.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('admirer.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('beloved.n.01'), 3.6375861597263857)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('betrothed.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('boyfriend.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('darling.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('girlfriend.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('idolizer.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('inamorata.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('inamorato.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('kisser.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('necker.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('petter.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('romeo.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('soul_mate.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('squeeze.n.04'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('beloved.n.01'), Synset('sweetheart.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('desire.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('sexual_desire.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('love.n.04'), 3.6375861597263857)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('aphrodisia.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('anaphrodisia.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('passion.n.05'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('sensuality.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('amorousness.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('fetish.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('libido.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('lecherousness.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('nymphomania.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('satyriasis.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.04'), Synset('the_hots.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('bowling_score.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('football_score.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('baseball_score.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('basketball_score.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('number.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('score.n.03'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('stroke.n.06'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('birdie.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('bogey.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('deficit.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('double-bogey.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('duck.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('eagle.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('double_eagle.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('game.n.06'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('lead.n.07'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('love.n.05'), 3.6375861597263857)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('match.n.05'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('love.n.05'), Synset('par.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('bondage.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('outercourse.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('safe_sex.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('sexual_activity.n.01'), 2.9444389791664407)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('conception.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('sexual_intercourse.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('pleasure.n.05'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), 3.6375861597263857)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('carnal_abuse.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('coupling.n.03'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('reproduction.n.05'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('foreplay.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('perversion.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('autoeroticism.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('promiscuity.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('lechery.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('homosexuality.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('bisexuality.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('heterosexuality.n.01'), 2.538973871058276)
(Synset('sexual_love.n.02'), Synset('bestiality.n.02'), 2.538973871058276)
# ...
```

Comment: wondering what all these sports terms like baseball_score, bogey, double_eagle have to do with love? :-) Ok got it. ['love']: a score of zero in tennis or squash

Answer (score 7):

First we have to ask the questions "What is synonym?", "Can synonyms be queried from the surface/root word?".

In WordNet, you have similar words representing the same concept under this term call the `Synset` and not at the surface word level.

To get synset's synonyms in the coverage of your example, you would require more than wordnet, possibly some semantic similarity methods to extract the other words.

I couldn't give you a JAWS explanation of what i mean above but from WordNet in NLTK interface for python. You can see that WN is insufficient for the coverage you want.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
for ss in wn.synsets('love'): # Each synset represents a diff concept.
  print ss.definition
  print ss.lemma_names
  print
```

**Code above outputs:**

```
a strong positive emotion of regard and affection
['love']

any object of warm affection or devotion; 
['love', 'passion']

a beloved person; used as terms of endearment
['beloved', 'dear', 'dearest', 'honey', 'love']

a deep feeling of sexual desire and attraction
['love', 'sexual_love', 'erotic_love']

a score of zero in tennis or squash
['love']

sexual activities (often including sexual intercourse) between two people
['sexual_love', 'lovemaking', 'making_love', 'love', 'love_life']

have a great affection or liking for
['love']

get pleasure from
['love', 'enjoy']

be enamored or in love with
['love']

have sexual intercourse with
['sleep_together', 'roll_in_the_hay', 'love', 'make_out', 'make_love', 'sleep_with', 'get_laid', 'have_sex', 'know', 'do_it', 'be_intimate', 'have_intercourse', 'have_it_away', 'have_it_off', 'screw', 'fuck', 'jazz', 'eff', 'hump', 'lie_with', 'bed', 'have_a_go_at_it', 'bang', 'get_it_on', 'bonk']
```

Comment: definition and lemma_names may need bracket I think

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at the [RiWordNet (RiTa) code](https://github.com/dhowe/RiTa/blob/master/src/rita/RiWordNet.java) (see `getAllSynonyms` method) and found that it generates synonyms by giving you all lemmas of **synsets**, **hyponyms**, **similar tos**, **also sees**, and **coordinate names**. I didn't include *coordinate names* but added *antonyms*. Furthermore, I added synset names and "synonym type" to my data so that I could make use of other Wordnet data like [**definition** and/or **examples**](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html#words). Here's my code in python and the output:

```
'''Synonym generator using NLTK WordNet Interface: http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html
    'ss': synset
    'hyp': hyponym
    'sim': similar to
    'ant': antonym
    'also' also see

'''

from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


def get_all_synsets(word, pos=None):
    for ss in wn.synsets(word):
        for lemma in ss.lemma_names():
            yield (lemma, ss.name())


def get_all_hyponyms(word, pos=None):
    for ss in wn.synsets(word, pos=pos):
            for hyp in ss.hyponyms():
                for lemma in hyp.lemma_names():
                    yield (lemma, hyp.name())


def get_all_similar_tos(word, pos=None):
    for ss in wn.synsets(word):
            for sim in ss.similar_tos():
                for lemma in sim.lemma_names():
                    yield (lemma, sim.name())


def get_all_antonyms(word, pos=None):
    for ss in wn.synsets(word, pos=None):
        for sslema in ss.lemmas():
            for antlemma in sslema.antonyms():
                    yield (antlemma.name(), antlemma.synset().name())


def get_all_also_sees(word, pos=None):
        for ss in wn.synsets(word):
            for also in ss.also_sees():
                for lemma in also.lemma_names():
                    yield (lemma, also.name())


def get_all_synonyms(word, pos=None):
    for x in get_all_synsets(word, pos):
        yield (x[0], x[1], 'ss')
    for x in get_all_hyponyms(word, pos):
        yield (x[0], x[1], 'hyp')
    for x in get_all_similar_tos(word, pos):
        yield (x[0], x[1], 'sim')
    for x in get_all_antonyms(word, pos):
        yield (x[0], x[1], 'ant')
    for x in get_all_also_sees(word, pos):
        yield (x[0], x[1], 'also')

for x in get_all_synonyms('love'):
    print x
```

**The output for 'love' and 'brave':**

**Love**

```
(u'love', u'love.n.01', 'ss')
(u'love', u'love.n.02', 'ss')
(u'passion', u'love.n.02', 'ss')
(u'beloved', u'beloved.n.01', 'ss')
(u'dear', u'beloved.n.01', 'ss')
(u'dearest', u'beloved.n.01', 'ss')
(u'honey', u'beloved.n.01', 'ss')
(u'love', u'beloved.n.01', 'ss')
(u'love', u'love.n.04', 'ss')
(u'sexual_love', u'love.n.04', 'ss')
(u'erotic_love', u'love.n.04', 'ss')
(u'love', u'love.n.05', 'ss')
(u'sexual_love', u'sexual_love.n.02', 'ss')
(u'lovemaking', u'sexual_love.n.02', 'ss')
(u'making_love', u'sexual_love.n.02', 'ss')
(u'love', u'sexual_love.n.02', 'ss')
(u'love_life', u'sexual_love.n.02', 'ss')
(u'love', u'love.v.01', 'ss')
(u'love', u'love.v.02', 'ss')
(u'enjoy', u'love.v.02', 'ss')
(u'love', u'love.v.03', 'ss')
(u'sleep_together', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'roll_in_the_hay', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'love', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'make_out', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'make_love', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'sleep_with', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'get_laid', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'have_sex', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'know', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'do_it', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'be_intimate', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'have_intercourse', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'have_it_away', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'have_it_off', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'screw', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'fuck', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'jazz', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'eff', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'hump', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'lie_with', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'bed', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'have_a_go_at_it', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'bang', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'get_it_on', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'bonk', u'sleep_together.v.01', 'ss')
(u'agape', u'agape.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'agape', u'agape.n.02', 'hyp')
(u'agape_love', u'agape.n.02', 'hyp')
(u'amorousness', u'amorousness.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'enamoredness', u'amorousness.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'ardor', u'ardor.n.02', 'hyp')
(u'ardour', u'ardor.n.02', 'hyp')
(u'benevolence', u'benevolence.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'devotion', u'devotion.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'devotedness', u'devotion.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'filial_love', u'filial_love.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'heartstrings', u'heartstrings.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'lovingness', u'lovingness.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'caring', u'lovingness.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'loyalty', u'loyalty.n.02', 'hyp')
(u'puppy_love', u'puppy_love.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'calf_love', u'puppy_love.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'crush', u'puppy_love.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'infatuation', u'puppy_love.n.01', 'hyp')
(u'worship', u'worship.n.02', 'hyp')
(u'adoration', u'worship.n.02', 'hyp')
(u'adore', u'adore.v.01', 'hyp')
(u'care_for', u'care_for.v.02', 'hyp')
(u'cherish', u'care_for.v.02', 'hyp')
(u'hold_dear', u'care_for.v.02', 'hyp')
(u'treasure', u'care_for.v.02', 'hyp')
(u'dote', u'dote.v.02', 'hyp')
(u'love', u'love.v.03', 'hyp')
(u'get_off', u'get_off.v.06', 'hyp')
(u'romance', u'romance.v.02', 'hyp')
(u'fornicate', u'fornicate.v.01', 'hyp')
(u'take', u'take.v.35', 'hyp')
(u'have', u'take.v.35', 'hyp')
(u'hate', u'hate.n.01', 'ant')
(u'hate', u'hate.v.01', 'ant')
```

**Brave**

```
(u'brave', u'brave.n.01', 'ss')
(u'brave', u'brave.n.02', 'ss')
(u'weather', u'weather.v.01', 'ss')
(u'endure', u'weather.v.01', 'ss')
(u'brave', u'weather.v.01', 'ss')
(u'brave_out', u'weather.v.01', 'ss')
(u'brave', u'brave.a.01', 'ss')
(u'courageous', u'brave.a.01', 'ss')
(u'audacious', u'audacious.s.01', 'ss')
(u'brave', u'audacious.s.01', 'ss')
(u'dauntless', u'audacious.s.01', 'ss')
(u'fearless', u'audacious.s.01', 'ss')
(u'hardy', u'audacious.s.01', 'ss')
(u'intrepid', u'audacious.s.01', 'ss')
(u'unfearing', u'audacious.s.01', 'ss')
(u'brave', u'brave.s.03', 'ss')
(u'braw', u'brave.s.03', 'ss')
(u'gay', u'brave.s.03', 'ss')
(u'desperate', u'desperate.s.04', 'sim')
(u'heroic', u'desperate.s.04', 'sim')
(u'gallant', u'gallant.s.01', 'sim')
(u'game', u'game.s.02', 'sim')
(u'gamy', u'game.s.02', 'sim')
(u'gamey', u'game.s.02', 'sim')
(u'gritty', u'game.s.02', 'sim')
(u'mettlesome', u'game.s.02', 'sim')
(u'spirited', u'game.s.02', 'sim')
(u'spunky', u'game.s.02', 'sim')
(u'lionhearted', u'lionhearted.s.01', 'sim')
(u'stalwart', u'stalwart.s.03', 'sim')
(u'stouthearted', u'stalwart.s.03', 'sim')
(u'undaunted', u'undaunted.s.02', 'sim')
(u'valiant', u'valiant.s.01', 'sim')
(u'valorous', u'valiant.s.01', 'sim')
(u'bold', u'bold.a.01', 'sim')
(u'colorful', u'colorful.a.02', 'sim')
(u'colourful', u'colorful.a.02', 'sim')
(u'timid', u'timid.n.01', 'ant')
(u'cowardly', u'cowardly.a.01', 'ant')
(u'adventurous', u'adventurous.a.01', 'also')
(u'adventuresome', u'adventurous.a.01', 'also')
(u'bold', u'bold.a.01', 'also')
(u'resolute', u'resolute.a.01', 'also')
(u'unafraid', u'unafraid.a.01', 'also')
(u'fearless', u'unafraid.a.01', 'also')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using **RitaWN** instead of **JAWS**? I see it is listed as one of the available API in http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#Java
I also see it has `getAllSynonyms()` method, they provide an example and it works.

Check this out:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import rita.*;

public class Synonyms {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Would pass in a PApplet normally, but we don't need to here
    RiWordNet wordnet = new RiWordNet("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WordNet\\2.1");

    // Get a random noun
    String word = "love";//wordnet.getRandomWord("n");
    // Get max 15 synonyms
    String[] synonyms = wordnet.getAllSynonyms(word, "v");

    System.out.println("Random noun: " + word);
    if (synonyms != null) {
        // Sort alphabetically
        Arrays.sort(synonyms);
        for (int i = 0; i < synonyms.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Synonym " + i + ": " + synonyms[i]);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No synyonyms!");
    }
}
```

Make sure to get the latest downloads and documentation from http://www.rednoise.org/rita/wordnet-old/documentation/index.htm