# Is Python has any english dictionary that returns a list of words with the same meaning?

Tags: python

For example, input USA, output America. Is that such module? I use it for Natural Language Processing.

Comment: You can find synonyms with NLTK's Synset.

Comment: About 35 countries collectively cringed at your example.

Comment: I think you're asking for a "thesaurus".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get NLTK module: http://nltk.org/install.html

import corpus:http://nltk.org/data.html

Play arround:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('USA')
```

Comment: thanks, but answer is [Synset('united_states.n.01'), Synset('united_states_army.n.01')]?

Comment: try something simmilar with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15739472/2244175