# How to get a word as a NLTK Synset form for comparison purpose?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, synonym

I am trying to compare the similarity of two word with `w1.wup_similarity(w2)` from NLTK. One synonym and the original one if possible.

Yet I don't know how to create w1 and w2. Indeed, according to [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-synonymsantonyms-nltk-wordnet-python/), it seems I need a `Synset` from the class 'nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset. Yet when I try to put w1, let say `in` into a Synset object mode, it only gives me a synonym, `inch`. I would like to have `in` :/

Comment: You asked for `synsets` (pl.) - and you got the list of them. It is up to you which one to select.

Comment: @DYZ True ! I updated

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15739472/610569 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19383914/610569

Comment: @DYZ, different synsets for the same word are actually different meanings.

Comment: @alvas Thanks for the link. I begin to understand. So if I just want the similiarity between a string `in` and synonyms from it to select the one I want to keep I have no options ?

Comment: Wordnet is indexed on "concept"/"synset" not words. Distance between synsets are clear. But not words/lemma. So if you start with the word/lemma, you have a pre-task of deciding which synset should the word/lemma be before you can get a comparison between two synsets. In short, you get more mileage with word2vec or word embeddings not wordnet if you're working with words/lemmas.

Comment: @alvas Yes, I work with words indeed and I wanted to get the synonyms of them. But it seems that `wordnet` isn't what will save me indeed as far as I get something that look like `in` (the preposition in, like _I am in the plane_) and I had to reach wordnet.synsets(word)[3] ot get to something like this. Too bad . I will watch the other two packages then.

Comment: @alvas I know. So what?